# How to send JSON data as parameter from C# to Jersey RESTful Service

Tags: c#, json, web-services, rest, post

I have a C# Console program. I just want to send JSON data to a POST RESTful service. Which approach should I follow?

```
@Path("/SetInfo")
public class SetInfo {

    @POST
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })   
    public String AuthMySQL(String json) {
        System.out.println("The JAX-RS runtime automatically stored my JSON request data: " + json);
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.........

C# code......for sending JSON Data to webservice (post).....

```
 var webAddr = "http://localhost:8080/TestWebservice/rest/SetInfo";
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"Name\":\"MR.X\",\"ID\":\"AH1J4\"}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new         StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.Write(result);

        }
```